# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError created when constructing an object within a switch

Tags: java, switch-statement, runtime-error

Within a switch I create an instance of a class Hive after the object is created it returns to my switch and hits the break before then coming up with an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Garden.fileReader(Garden.java:141)
at Garden.<init>(Garden.java:28)
at Garden.<clinit>(Garden.java:10)'
```

The error occurs after running through the switch statement then into a separate class to construct the object and when returning and hitting the break the error pops up

```
public class Garden {
    public static final Garden GARDEN = new Garden();   //line 10------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int mainI = 0;
        while (mainI != 100) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            GARDEN.anotherDay();
            mainI++;
        }
    }
    static HashMap<String, Hive> HiveMap = new HashMap<String, Hive>();

    private Garden() {

        fileReader();   //line 28 --------------------------
        System.out.println("fileReader worked");
    }



    protected void fileReader() { // asks for file name for config file

        //removed try catch code that uses Scanner to get input from console
        // to select a file that is set to configFile

        Scanner configScanner = new Scanner(configFile);
        int k = 0;

        while (configScanner.hasNextLine() == true) {
            String inputLine = configScanner.nextLine();
            //removed long if statment to set k

            switch (k) {
            case 1:
                intFinder(k, inputLine);
                Hive hive = new Hive(honeyInput, pollenInput, royalJellyInput);
                HiveMap.put("hive" + hiveName, hive); line 141-------------
                break; // it gets to this break then throws the error

                // removed code
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        cmdReader.close();
        configScanner.close();
    }
```

The constructor for hive is

```
protected Hive(int honeyStart, int royalJellyStart, int pollenStart)
{
    bees = new ArrayList<Bee>();
    this.setHoney(honeyStart);
    this.setRoyalJelly(royalJellyStart);
    this.setPollen(pollenStart);
}
```

Sorry for posting so much code but my only idea to what was going wrong was configScanner losing data when code was ran in another class and it isn’t that so I have no idea what’s going wrong any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because at the time the initializer of `Garden GARDEN` runs, the `HiveMap` is not initialized yet. Move the line that initializes `HiveMap` to a line ahead of `Garden GARDEN` to fix the problem:

```
static HashMap<String, Hive> HiveMap = new HashMap<String, Hive>();
public static final Garden GARDEN = new Garden();
```

The reason why this fixes the problem is that static initializers run in textual order. The `Garden()` constructor assumes that `HiveMap` is non-null, because it tries to put data in it:

```
HiveMap.put("hive" + hiveName, hive);
```

Comment: thank you something so simple been trying to work out what was causing it for about an hour playing with bits all over the place

Answer (score 1):

Static things are evaluated in order.  On line 10, you're trying to create a `new Garden()`, which tries to access the static member `HiveMap`, but it hasn't been initialized yet.  Just move the `new Garden()` into the `main` method.

Comment: moving the new Garden() into main causes errors when trying to access it from outside of Garden